# Looking for an alternative solution of ARRAY_CONTAINS for Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using a nested data structure (array) to store multivalued attributes for Spark table. I am using array_contains(array, value) in Spark SQL to check if the array contains the value but it seems there is a performance issue. It takes a lot of time for a large Spark table. Is there any alternative solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't supply a lot of details on what exactly you are doing - if you are accessing the values inside the array a lot if can be beneficial to add columns with the value(s) from the array, e.g. by using [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-)

Comment: yeah, thats a good idea. especially, if you store this exploded table with a columnar storage format like parquet or orc: you might be able to find the corresponding rows for future queries relatively quick. i guess the columnar way to store an array does not provide O(1) access to the rows which contain the requested element that you ask for in ARRAY_CONTAINS.

Comment: I am using Parquet file.

Comment: @Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz I am joining two tables where the join condition is based on ARRAY_CONTAINS. Will it be feasible if I explode the array type column before JOIN operation?